# Pausing the game when entering background

Tags: ios, objective-c, gamekit

I'm trying to make my game pause(while saving the current state of the game like timer values and scores) when the user enters the background. I know I have to implement this in

`- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` method

But I have no idea how to. I'm guessing I first have to check if the current view controller the user is currently on is the game scene, and then, if it is, I call the method for pausing. Am I getting the right idea? I don't know how to access the current view controller. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: I'm just using the `UIKit` nothing special as it's a pretty simple game.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that? I've been trying to figure that out for hours.

Comment: But what if the pause method is in a different view controller? How would I get to that view controller?

Comment: Never ever an object outside your game controller object is responsible for pausing and resuming the game. that's your game controller's job! observe any necessary events in there and react on them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

subclass UINavigationController and add the view controller as an observer for UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification

```
@interface GameViewController : UIViewController
@end

@implementation GameViewController
- (void) init {
   self = [super init];
   if (self) {
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(saveGameState) name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object: nil];
   }
}

- (void) delloc {
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object: nil];
}

- (void) saveGameState {
//do the things you neeed to do
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is getting your game view controller to know the application will enter background?

When your game view controller appear, use the Notification Center to register it to listen for the UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myBackgroundHanlerMethod:) name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

and handle the notification inside a

```
- (void)myBackgroundHanlerMethod:(NSNotification *)notification;
```

Comment: Note1: You don't have to send the UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, the application will send it for you (look at UIApplication documentation)

Comment: Note2: Your must stop observing the notification when your gameviewcontroller isn't displayed anymore. (Register inside viewWillAppear and unregister inside viewWillDisappear for example).

Comment: Guess I first have to learn how to use NSNotification class. Thanks!